# How to delete the rows that start with "C" with awk?

Tags: shell, awk

How can I delete the rows that start with "C" from a text file using `awk`?

Any suggestions please.

Comment: As a sidenote, you might find [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) to be very helpful in the future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If data is in file `data.txt`, then

With `awk`:

```
awk '!/^C/' data.txt
```

With `grep`:

```
grep -v ^C data.txt
```

Display all lines without "C" at the start.

`^C` means to match letter "C" at *start* of line. `!` in awk, and `-v` in grep negate the match.

Answer (score 2):

You may:

```
awk '!/^C/{print $0}'
```

Answer (score 1):

That is elementary:

```
awk '/^[^C]/'
```

When you omit `{}` section of an awk command that means the same as `{print}` or *print the line*. And `//` is re-filter that is applied to stdin. Only that lines will be processed that conform to the filter.

`^[^C]` is a regula rexpression. The first `^` is an anchor, it means *the beginning of the line*; and `[^C]` is a symbol class that means *any character except C*.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
sed -i~ '/^C/d' inFile
```

Comment: While it isn't exactly what the user asked for -- since it uses `sed` instead of `awk` -- my guess is that someone asking how to delete characters that start with "C" might want the safety of this answer. It actually changes the file instead of writing the result to stdout, and it renames the original with a tilde at the end.