# Remove unwanted lines from a text file starting with "abc" or "fgh"

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, text, str-replace

So I have a huge list and I have some serials on every line. I want to remove all unwanted lines starting with `234` and `467`. I want to do this using a batch file but it won't mind me if it's easier using php.

```
072345678
072567863
234567832
467890432
072345678
```

I want to remove with a batch file all the lines starting with `234` and `467` so edited text file will remain like this

```
072345678
072567863
072345678
```

Comment: Please share what you've tried.

Comment: i have tryed using this but its not working ren myFile.txt myFile.txt.old
findstr /v /b /c:"blabla" myFile.txt.old > myFile.txt

Answer (score 0):

Use findstr. It allows Regular Expressions (with `/R`). The carat (`^`) matches the beginning of the line. `/V` filters out lines that match (instead of filtering out lines that don't match).

```
type yourfile.txt | findstr /R /V "^234" | findstr /R /V "^467"
```

Answer (score 0):

in php you can use something like this

```
$text="072345678
072567863
234567832
467890432
072345678";
echo preg_replace('#^(234|467)([0-9]+)$#ims', '', $text);
```

file_get_contents to have data, then explode, foreach  on pregreplace and an if to not add empty lines, but using shell commands is faster

Answer (score 0):

This will most likely work for you

```
$data = file("./foo.txt");
$matches = array('234', '467');
$out = array();

foreach($data AS $line) 
{
   // if not matches 234 OR 467, add to out array
   $pattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $matches) . ')/'; // $pattern = /^(234|467)/
   if(! preg_match($pattern, $string))
   {
       $out[] = $line;
   }
}

// open and lock foofile
$fp = fopen("./foo.txt", "w+");
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);

// rewrite foo with valid content line by line
foreach($out AS $line) 
{
    fwrite($fp, $line);
}
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
```

If you are looking to do this to many files, you can always also turn this into a function

```
function replaceFileData(array $filesList, array $matches)
{
    foreach ($filesList AS $file)
    {
        if (file_exists($file) && ! empty($matches))
        {
            $data = file($file)
            $out  = array();

            foreach($data AS $line) 
            {
               // if not matches 234 OR 467, add to out array
               $pattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $matches) . ')/'; // $pattern = /^(234|467)/
               if(! preg_match($pattern, $string))
               {
                    $out[] = $line;

                    $fp = fopen($file, "w+");
                    flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
                    foreach($out AS $line) 
                    {
                        fwrite($fp, $line);
                    }
                    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
                    fclose($fp);
               }
            }
        }
    }
}


replaceFileData(array('foo.txt', 'bar.txt'), array(234, 567));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -v ^234 file.txt

grep -v ^467 file.txt
```

There is a lot of solutions, have a look at previous posts: [How to delete the rows that start with "C" with awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117493/how-to-delete-the-rows-that-start-with-c-with-awk)

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\ type test.txt
072345678
072567863
234567832
467890432
072345678

C:\ findstr /B /V "234 467" test.txt
072345678
072567863
072345678
```

Answer (score 0):

In batch you can do something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (input.txt) do (
    set line=%%i
    set line=!line:~0,3!
    if !line! NEQ 234 (
        if !line! NEQ 467 (
            echo %%i >>out.txt
        )
    )
)
```